# Scientific Notation - bug in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, scientific-notation

Yeah I know it's hard to believe - bug in .NET? But run this code in the command line app:

```
decimal x;

x = decimal.Parse("3.E-2", NumberStyles.Float);
Console.WriteLine(x);

x = decimal.Parse("5.72e9", NumberStyles.Float);
Console.WriteLine(x);

x = decimal.Parse("3.E−2", NumberStyles.Float);
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

I'm getting exception during the last parse. Saying:

```
System.FormatException : Input string was not in a correct format.
```

The value for the first and last parse are exactly the same. Tested on two different x64 machines compiled toward .NET 3.5 and 4.

Any idea what is going on? Any work-around?

Comment: The standard disclaimer applies (and is proven once again) : always assume your code is wrong *first* before screaming "framework bug! framework bug!"

Comment: i wonder how you typed that figure-dash or en-dash :/

Comment: it's U2012 Figure Dash , yeah how did u type that !?

Comment: Copy & Paste from the customer input file. Under my VS font, both characters looks the same - just here I can spot the difference :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The first and 3rd are not exactly the same.

in the 3rd you have a "longer" - sign, as a result it doesnt know what to do with it. Therefore you would need to check for that and replace it with the standard minus sign

Comment: Crikey, your name serves you well, BugFinder :-) Good catch!

Comment: Very well spotted - I've had other person looking at this before posting. ;)

Comment: The last dash appears to be the Unicode minus sign (or is it an en-dash?).

Comment: @BoltClock it's en-dash OR figure-dash

Comment: It's not dash, it's minus. I mean the proper one, not the hyphen-minus hybrid most people are used to have on their keyboard. Looks so much better than the regular one but even apps claiming full unicode support don't recongnize it.